# how to modify schema in openldap

Tags: ldap, schema

So I have a fresh installation of openldap on a debian 9 machine which currently looks like

[image: this]

It's going to be a database for telephone numbers, too keep it easy, I'll use this example: The database will be splitted into the city - the streets - and the people who live in this streets.

It should look like this: dc=city -> ou=street -> cn=nameofperson

So far so good, I try to create the first dc, for example New York like this:

```
root@ldap-test:/etc/ldap/ldif-import# ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/ldap/ldif-import/createcn.ldif
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
adding new entry "cn=NewYork"
ldap_add: Server is unwilling to perform (53)
        additional info: no global superior knowledge
```

and thats how the ldif file looks like:

```
dn: cn=NewYork
dc: NewYork
distinguishedName: dc=NewYork
name: NewYork
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
```

As this didn't work I thought of another way, to put the streets into nodomain, just to check if it will work this way, but it seems that the schema is missing 
distinguishedName and name. I looked into the default schemas and core.ldif has these entries, but they are commented out.

So I cant load this ldif:

```
dn: ou=broadway,dc=nodomain
distinguishedName: ou=broadway,dc=nodomain
name: broadway
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: broadway
```

.

```
root@ldap-test:/etc/ldap/ldif-import# ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/ldap/ldif-import/broadway.ldif
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
adding new entry "ou=broadway,dc=nodomain"
ldap_add: Object class violation (65)
        additional info: attribute 'distinguishedName' not allowed
```

So loading distinguishedName into the schema but it shows adding new entry

```
"cn=core,cn=schema,cn=config"
ldap_add: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
        additional info: olcAttributeTypes: Duplicate attributeType: "2.5.4.49"
```

I dont understand why, because it's not even loaded in `/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config/cn=schema/cn={*}*.ldif`

Anybody knows what to do?

Answer (score 1):

- `name` isn't a generally used attribute, though `cn` (`commonName`) is.
- Don't attempt to add `distinguishedName`. `dn` already handles this. `dn` and `distinguishedName` are aliases for the same attribute, but only `dn` should be used for `ldapmodify` operations. This includes `ldapadd`.

---

Your first ldif is failing because:

1. Your ldap server is not configured to handle the `cn=NewYork` namingContext.
   2  You are attempting to add a distinguishedName attribute.
2. `objectClass: dcObject` has no attribute `name`

Your second ldif is failing because:

1. You are attempting to add a distinguishedName attribute.
2. `objectClass: organizationalUnit` has no attribute `name`

---

Side note: ldap attributes, including the parts used in rdn's, can have spaces in them. Use quotes as appropriate.